# Developing Glue ETL script locally - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm currently developing ETL scripts locally using the AWS Glue ETL library.

I'm facing an issue when extracting data from S3 bucket as DynamicFrame.

When I want to convert to a DataFrame using toDF(), it will always trigger this exception:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o52.toDF
```

...

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 29)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy15.requestConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.lazySeek(S3AInputStream.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:364)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.getCompressedData(DecompressorStream.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.readers.BufferedStream.read(DynamicRecordReader.scala:91)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:489)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:215)
```

I tried the same code on AWS Glue DevEndpoint and it works fine. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go with java8, your issue will be resolved

check java -version

Comment: My java is already java8:
openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: @DmcZx I was wondering if you managed to solve this issue? I am having the same issues

Comment: @kabeersvohra Sorry. Last I tried I was still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running the dev env with following specs:

- Scala version 2.11.12
- Spark version 2.4.3
- Glue 1.0.0

To fix it, add the following line to the spark configuration in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.master local
```

Alternatively, depending on how you are running your job, you can configure this dynamically if you are in control of the spark context. i.e.

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local").setAppName("My app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

I have found this happens when running in local mode with multiple threads, I have found that increasing `fs.s3.connection.maximum` or `fs.s3a.connection.maximum` does not fix the issue. Although this post indicates that it should https://kb.databricks.com/jobs/job-fails-connection-pool.html